# Rank and order of subpopulation in distributed genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I am interested in plotting the performance of individual subpopulations in the island based distributed genetic algorithms. I saw a couple of research works that calculate the rank and order of subpopulations and plot the rank against the generations to understand how the subpopulations evolve?

I could not understand how the rank of each subpopulation is calculated?

Could anyone please explain.

Comment: Did you try averaging the fitness scores of the members of the subpopulation and maybe taking the top fitness score from the subpopulation and using that. Those two values would allow you to rank and order your subpopulations pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the rank of sub-populations is assigned based on a quality of the sub-populations. Some common qualities to use for this are the average fitness value of the sub-population, the best fitness value of the sub-population, etc...

The rank may be used as measure to order the population.